# Xamarin Forms XAML Image control has quit working

Tags: image, xamarin.forms

I have a working app that displays images. I started a new app and copied the code but this new app does not display images. Puzzled, I have tried many, many things to debug it. I eventually made a plain vanilla new project with only an Image control. As usual, I added the picture to the project using Add Existing Item. I confirmed that the image is there. It does not display the image. I noticed something different in Solution Explorer. Under the Solution, the first project has Dependencies listed under it. This is new. My previous apps have never had that. Now every new project I create has it. I also noticed that the Properties of the image was Build Action of None. I tried changing it to Content but that did not help. At this point, I am baffled and stuck.  Did something change in Visual Studio? Here is the image test XAML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageTest"
             x:Class="ImageTest.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Image Source="gr8oz.png" />
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

As I said, I have a working app that has been released. I copied this code into a new app and it does not work. In my investigation, I have found that the Image control does not work for me anymore.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OFamV2"
             Style="{StaticResource MyContentPage}"
             x:Class="OFamV2.MainPage"
             Title="Main Menus">
    <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button x:Name="TreeButton"
                    Text="Don and Iola Osborne"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    Style="{StaticResource MyButtons}"
                    Clicked="TreeButton_Clicked" />
        <Button x:Name="IndianNamesButton" 
                    Text="Indian Names"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    Style="{StaticResource MyButtons}"
                    Clicked="IndianNamesButton_Clicked" />
        <Button x:Name="NextPageButton" 
                    Text="Indian Potpourri"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    Style="{StaticResource MyButtons}"
                    Clicked="NextPageButton_Clicked" />
        <Button x:Name="OldPhotos"
                    Text="Old Photos"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    Style="{StaticResource MyButtons}"
                    Clicked="OldPhotos_Clicked" />
        <Button x:Name="ReunionButton" 
                    Text="Family Reunion"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    Style="{StaticResource MyButtons}"
                    Clicked="ReunionButton_Clicked"
                    />
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image                  
                    Source="Photos/gr8oz.png"
                    Style="{StaticResource MyImage}"
                    Margin="0,30,0,0"
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    />
                <Image
                    Source = "Photos/logo.bmp" 
                    Style="{StaticResource MyImage}"
                    Margin="150,0,0,0"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    WidthRequest="200"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"/>
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

I have searched and read everything that I can find (and yes, I have read the Microsoft doc about the Image class).

I am also curious why Dependencies suddenly appeared in the Shared Project folder. This is new too. How do I resolve them? See screenshot.
[Dependencies under OFamV2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKKwJ.png)

I uninstalled Visual Studio, deleted the folder, reinstalled Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.8.8 and the problem is still there, even with a new project.

For Options, I select Cross Platform/ Mobile App/ Platform: Android and UWP/Code Sharing: .Net Standard.

Comment: What options are you selecting when creating the new project? There has always been a choice of using a "Shared project" or a "Portable Class Library project" (PCL) for the Xamarin.Forms shared code. PCL projects have been replaced with .NET Standard project which has the Dependencies pseudo folder. And did you normally put your image files in the shred project or in the app specific projects. I would need to see an old "working" app and a new "non-working" app to see exactly what you were doing before vs what you are doing now.

Comment: have you read the docs on using images?   The location and build action depends on the platform.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos

Comment: Hard to tell from your information, but have you added the images correctly? Make sure to add them to the correct folders in your platform project and set the build action correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Set image show you can see [here](http://%20http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/) , i think you have used that.

So reload your project,and rebuild it,you can try this.

More info:

1. [Here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34648/image-not-showing) is a similar disscussion about image show.
2. Suggest that better not copy code from other project about view,they may result some problems where you do not know.